# How to add meta tag in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have been trying to add meta tag like below.But it is not working. can anyone help me??any help would be appreciated.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { set } = Ember;
export default Ember.Route.extend({
 // inject the head data service
 headData: Ember.inject.service(),
 afterModel() {
   set(this, 'headData.title', 'Demo App');
 }
});
```

Comment: Is your `afterModel` getting executed at all?

Comment: Did you include `<meta property="og:title" content={{model.title}} />` in `app/templates/head.hbs` ?

Comment: yeah i added that too....but still it is not working @ kumkanillam

Comment: @Jure C yep it is getting executed.

Comment: To clarify, do you see the data in the service or is it not rendering? You won't see the meta tags if you use 'view source' without some server-side rendering. But developer tools will.